# How to name a policy for multimodel route in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, api, routes, authorization

I'm trying to write a policy for this route:

```
Route::delete(
    'users/{user}/locations/{location}',
    [UserLocationController::class, 'destroy'],
)->middleware('can:delete,user,location');
```

but I don't know how to name the policy to allow Laravel to find it automatically. I'm deleting records from `location_user` table, but I don't have model for this table. My policy function looks like this:

```
public function delete(User $user, User $userModel, Location $location)
{
    return $user->id === $userModel->id
        && $user->locations->contains($location->id);
}
```

I've tried names like `LocationUserPolicy`, `UserLocationPolicy`, `LocationPolicy`, but none of them works. Do you have any suggestions how to name the policy or how to write custom logic to allow Laravel to find it?

Comment: have you tried using `->name('foo'); ` to name the route?

Comment: how will it help me?

Comment: `Route::delete( 'users/{user}/locations/{location}', [UserLocationController::class, 'destroy'])->middleware('can:delete,user,location')->name('foo');` This will name your route to be used where ever you want. and you can include it using `route('foo')` to include in view.

Comment: but I'm not trying to name the route but the policy for the route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer right in the Laravel documentation :D The trick is in the changing the order of the can middleware attributes.

> The first element in the array will be used to determine which policy should be invoked, while the rest of the array elements are passed as parameters to the policy method and can be used for additional context when making authorization decisions.

So I changed my route to this:

```
Route::delete(
    'users/{user}/locations/{location}',
    [UserLocationController::class, 'destroy']
)->middleware('can:delete,location,user');
```

named the policy `LocationPolicy` (by first attribute) and changed my policy function to this:

```
public function delete(User $user, Location $location, User $model)
{
    return $user->id === $model->id
        && $user->locations->contains($location->id);
}
```

Now it works like a charm.